# Generate Covariance in Pandas as a New Value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a total of 4 columns in my dataframe. I would like to generate the Covariance between every row and its 1st lag row. How do I do the same? A subset of my dataframe along with the desired column 'Covariance' is given below:

```
 A1      A2      A3      A4      Covariance 
24.54   63.32   47.12   60.66      nan
16.33   64.39   49.72   56.94     73.43
46.38   55.94   42.35   73.43     50.27
```

Basically, the Covariance column should contain the value as if the COVARIANCE.P formula was used between a row and its lag in Microsoft EXCEL. As of now, I am generating new columns with the lag variables and trying to obtain the Covariance along a row of the data frame. This is the code that I have:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A1':[19, 20, 21],
               'A2':[24.54, 16.33, 46.38],
               'A3':[63.32, 64.39, 55.94],
               'A4':[47.12, 49.72, 42.35]})
df['Lag_A1'] = df['A1].shift(-1)
df['Lag_A2'] = df['A2].shift(-1)
df['Lag_A3'] = df['A3].shift(-1)
df['Lag_A4'] = df['A4].shift(-1)
Main = ['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4']
Lag_1 = ['Lag_1_A1', 'Lag_1_A2', 'Lag_1_A3', 'Lag_1_A4']
Lag_1_Cov = df.apply(lambda x: x[Main].T.cov(x[Lag_1].T))
```

However, this code does not work. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand.

```
df['Cov']=[df.iloc[:,:4].iloc[x].cov(df.iloc[:,:4].shift(1).iloc[x]) for x in range(len(df))]
df
Out[147]: 
      A1     A2     A3     A4  Covariance         Cov
0  24.54  63.32  47.12  60.66         NaN         NaN
1  16.33  64.39  49.72  56.94       73.43  369.981333
2  46.38  55.94  42.35  73.43       50.27  143.071233
```

Comment: this works! Thanks. However, it returns the sample covariance. I require the population covariance.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Wen  and @jpp! I used a combination of both of your codes to solve the problem. I basically created a np.cov function and combined it with iloc and looped it over the range of the df.

Comment: @GauthamKanthasamy that is great man :-) , you can consider upvote and accept ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `numpy` for this calculation. However, I cannot replicate your covariance values.

Note that we set `ddof = 0` for population covariance.

```
import numpy as np

arr = df.values
df['Covariance'] = [np.nan] + [np.cov(i, j, ddof=0)[0][1] for i, j in zip(arr, arr[1:])]
```

Result:

```
      A1     A2     A3     A4  Covariance
0  24.54  63.32  47.12  60.66         NaN
1  16.33  64.39  49.72  56.94  277.486000
2  46.38  55.94  42.35  73.43  107.303425
```

Comment: The first line of your code itself gives me an error!

Comment: Have you imported `numpy`? .. `import numpy as np`.

Comment: I did that. But some other error was causing the problem. Have corrected it now. However, I am still not getting the right results. Please can you explain the code so that I can modify it?

Comment: What are the "right results"? I can't match the results in your question.

Comment: This is a link to the file with the excel formula of what I want: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Z4z1FgVNzWB9Uo6_yIF3g5O5BGsvz9BH/view?usp=sharing Please have a look!